# Trouble configuring Hibernate cache -- org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage

Tags: hibernate, caching, configuration, jboss, ehcache

I'm deploying a Hibernate (v 4.1.5.SP1, validator 4.3.0.Final) application (a Jar file) running on a MySQL 5.5 db to JBoss 4.2.3.GA (can't change this).  I'm getting the error "org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage" when running the app, but it seems I've configured everythign correctly.  I'm using these Maven dependencies ...

```
            <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

The error is odd because I have the cache configured in my hibernate.cfg.xml file ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/MySqlDS</property>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
                <property name="show_sql">true</property>
                <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

                <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--  Caching -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>

                <mapping class="org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.model.Organization" />
                <mapping class="org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.model.Community" />
                <mapping class="org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.model.Domain" />
                <mapping class="org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.model.State" />
                <mapping class="org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.model.Country" />

        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is included in my META-INF/persistence.xml file, which is below ...

```
<persistence>
        <persistence-unit name="orgsclientunit" transaction-type="JTA">
                <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                <jta-data-source>java:/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
                <properties>
                        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
                        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">false</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
                        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

To override the JBoss classloaders, I include this file at META-INF/jboss.xml ...

```
<jboss>
        <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
                <!-- setup classLoader repository. java2ParentDelegation to always have
                        package libs override server libs for this application -->
                <loader-repository>
                        org.mainco.subco.orgs:loader=orgsclient
                        <loader-repository-config>
                                java2ParentDelegation=false
                        </loader-repository-config>
                </loader-repository>
        </class-loading>
</jboss>
```

Here is the complete stack trace.  What's the cause of this?

```
2012-08-16 11:01:37,195 ERROR [org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl] org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation^M
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation^M
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:720)^M
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:121)^M
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:51)^M
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:33)^M
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.AbstractTransactionService.startOperation(AbstractTransactionService.java:27)^M
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.saveOrganization(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:87)^M
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.getEODBOrganizations(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:221)^M
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.service.OrganizationServiceImpl.saveOrgsFromWebService(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:183)^M
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.quartz.UpdateOrgsJob.execute(UpdateOrgsJob.java:55)^M
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)^M
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)^M
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)^M
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)^M
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)^M
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)^M
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:249)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:268)^M
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:138)^M
        at $Proxy81.execute(Unknown Source)^M
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)^M
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)^M
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)^M
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate cache implementation^M
        at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:64)^M
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:214)^M
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)^M
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:713)^M
        ... 32 more^M
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]^M
        at org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider.buildCache(NoCacheProvider.java:21)^M
        at org.hibernate.cache.CacheFactory.createCache(CacheFactory.java:61)^M
    ... 35 more^M
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Is `hibernate.cache.provider_class` defined as `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if [this](http://affy.blogspot.in/2006/12/solving-second-level-cache-is-not.html) which I found with googling helps you...

It says you should configure `hibernate.cache.provider_class` as `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider`